# deferred for chaining ajax wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .when

I wanna using $.deferred objects to handle my recursive function's requests.

but here I have a problem that

- $.when **wont wait** for call1 success then do call2!
- it wont send the returned data from call1 to call2 function!

note : only want to implement my ajax's with async:true;

thanks in advance!

m.mov

```
    //*********************************************************************

    var i = 3; // just run the queue 3 times 

    function getNode(node_object_array)
    {
        $.when(call1(node_object_array)).then(call2);

        i--;
        if(i >= 0)
            getNode(next_level_childs);

    }

function call1(node_object_array)
    {
            var root_array = new Array();
        var d = new $.Deferred();

        $.each(node_object_array , function(index , each_root_node) {

            console.log("making request  for"+each_root_node.node_guid );
                 $.ajax({
                    url: url ,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) {
                        root_array.push(getNodeData(json));
                        console.log("success request for"+each_root_node.node_guid );
                    },
                });
        });

        d.resolve(root_array);
        return d;
    }



    //****** call2 which receive data from call1 and call some $.ajax's ****
    function call2(data)
    {
            var next_level_childs = new Array();
        var d = new $.Deferred();

        $.each(data , function(index , each_root_node) {
            $.each(each_root_node.childs , function(index , each_root_node_child) {
                console.log("making request for "+each_root_node_child );
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url ,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async : false,
                        success: function(json) {
                            console.log("success request for"+each_root_node_child );
                            next_level_childs.push(getNodeData(json));
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
        d.resolve(next_level_childs);
        return d;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you resolve the Deferred before your ajax call completes, then $.when will consider it finished and will call the next function (call2). What you need to do is resolve it on the success/fail of your ajax call inside call1.

Edit: You actually need to combine all the promises from your ajax calls so you only resolve the deferred after all of them have completed. I only just noticed the $.each call.

Comment: thanks Vlad! its works now! I do some refactoring my code. currently I will take all of $.ajax calls to one object and call with **$.when.apply** and others things also works fine! thnx buddy! sorry for my reputation that I dont have any! lol

Comment: It's ok. Glad I could help.